# HTML Code - Create send the input of a page to pdf

Tags: html, pdf

i'm new to this world, so what i'm trying to do is create a form that you select specific field when you create an object and send the input to and pdf output.

this is the code that i have, but i dont now if i'm doing the thing good
please help, best regards, and how can send all this input to a POST and past it to a pdf format?

```html
<html>


<body>

<h1> Create A Bridge Domain </h1>


<form>
  Name of the BD:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
  Name of the VRF that belongs this BD:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname">
</form>


<p>L2 Unknown Unicast</p>
<select name="L2 Unknown Unicast ">
  <option value="L2 Unknown Unicast">Flood</option>
  <option value="none">none</option>
</select> 

<p>L3 Unknown Unicast</p>
<select name="L3 Unknown Unicast ">
  <option value="L3 Unknown Unicast">Flood</option>
  <option value="none">none</option>
</select> 

<p>Multi Destination Flooding</p>
<select name="Multi Destination Flooding ">
  <option value="Multi Destination Flooding">Flood in BD</option>
  <option value="none">none</option>
</select> 

<p>ARP Flooding</p>
<select name="ARP Flooding  ">
  <option value="ARP Flooding ">Enable</option>
  <option value="ARP Flooding ">Disable</option>
</select> 

<p>Subnets</p>
<select name="Subnets">
  <option value="Subnets">Enable</option>
  <option value="Subnets">Disable</option>
</select> 



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Note: This should be a comment but I can't comment yet so I'll write here instead.

Hello word!

HTML cannot do your request, it's just markup language to show front-end result , you're required back-end language to handle this part.

There are plenty of backend language, for example: php.
I did a research and there it is [Convert HTML + CSS to PDF with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/391005/convert-html-css-to-pdf-with-php)

The idea is gather user input, generate page and convert it to pdf.

You need basic PHP knowledge to get it works. Good luck.

Comment: yeah, thanks a lot Momo, i already realized that i need php, with the post method and a form to create an action to the input, if a have a new question about it i'm going to post it! thanks!

Comment: Hello Momo i'm having a problem with the